# GMAP & Location - Coordinates show but cannot show node information

Tags: drupal, google-maps, drupal-6, drupal-views

I set up a view with a type of gmap.  If I change it to grid, all of the field values output fine.  When I switch to gmap, the coordinates show up on the map but I can't get any info on the coordinates/markers.

I am very very stuck.  I have gone at this several different ways.  You can see the example here: http://speakitnow.com/immersionschools

```
<div class="views-field-title">
      <label class="views-label-title">
        Title:
      </label>
      <span class="field-content"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running into the same issue even with 6.x-1.1-rc1 it looks like the version here fixes the issue: http://drupal.org/node/95786

Answer (score 0):

which versions of the modules are you using?

There is a patch at [the issue queue for gmap](http://drupal.org/node/623234#comment-2279838) that fixes some of the issues

If it helps, here is my export of a view that is similar to what you're trying to achieve:
http://www.thegalleryguide.co.uk/galleries

This is on Drupal 6.15, with views 6.x-2.8, GMap 6.x-1.1-rc1, GMap Location 6.x-1.1-rc1

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'galleries_map';
$view->description = 'Galleries - Map';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('relationships', array(
  'nid' => array(
    'id' => 'nid',
    'table' => 'location_instance',
    'field' => 'nid',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'field_images_fid' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'thumb_linked',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => 1,
      'multiple_number' => '1',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => 0,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_images_fid',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_images',
    'field' => 'field_images_fid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'street' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'style' => 'both',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'street',
    'table' => 'location',
    'field' => 'street',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'postal_code' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'postal_code',
    'table' => 'location',
    'field' => 'postal_code',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'teaser' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 1,
      'max_length' => '100',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'teaser',
    'table' => 'node_revisions',
    'field' => 'teaser',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
  ),
  'tid' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'type' => 'separator',
    'separator' => ', ',
    'empty' => '',
    'link_to_taxonomy' => 0,
    'limit' => 1,
    'vids' => array(
      '3' => 3,
      '2' => 0,
      '4' => 0,
      '5' => 0,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'tid',
    'table' => 'term_node',
    'field' => 'tid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'view_node' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'text' => 'More...',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'view_node',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'view_node',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'distance' => array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'origin' => 'user',
    'units' => 'km',
    'latitude' => '',
    'longitude' => '',
    'id' => 'distance',
    'table' => 'location',
    'field' => 'distance',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'gallery' => 'gallery',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('title', 'Galleries');
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 0);
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'gmap');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'grouping' => '',
  'macro' => '[gmap ]',
  'datasource' => 'location',
  'latfield' => 'field_images_fid',
  'lonfield' => 'field_images_fid',
  'markers' => 'static',
  'markerfield' => 'field_images_fid',
  'markertype' => 'small blue',
));
$handler->override_option('row_options', array(
  'inline' => array(),
  'separator' => '',
  'hide_empty' => 0,
));
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->override_option('path', 'galleries');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'normal',
  'title' => 'Galleries',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => '1',
  'name' => 'primary-links',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
));
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Nearest galleries', 'block_1');
$handler->override_option('relationships', array(
  'nid' => array(
    'label' => 'Location: Node',
    'required' => 1,
    'id' => 'nid',
    'table' => 'location_instance',
    'field' => 'nid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'distance' => array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'origin' => 'user',
    'units' => 'km',
    'latitude' => '',
    'longitude' => '',
    'id' => 'distance',
    'table' => 'location',
    'field' => 'distance',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'nid',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'nid' => array(
    'default_action' => 'default',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'node',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'break_phrase' => 0,
    'not' => 0,
    'id' => 'nid',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'nid',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
      '4' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
    ),
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'nid',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'webform' => 0,
      'poll' => 0,
      'image' => 0,
      'artist' => 0,
      'exhibition' => 0,
      'faqs' => 0,
      'gallery' => 0,
      'link' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
      'story' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '2' => 0,
      '4' => 0,
      '5' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'image_size' => array(
      '_original' => '_original',
      'thumbnail' => 'thumbnail',
      'preview' => 'preview',
    ),
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'gallery' => 'gallery',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'distance' => array(
    'operator' => 'dist',
    'value' => array(
      'latitude' => '',
      'longitude' => '',
      'postal_code' => '',
      'country' => '',
      'search_distance' => '100',
      'search_units' => 'mile',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'type' => 'latlon',
    'identifier' => 'dist',
    'id' => 'distance',
    'table' => 'location',
    'field' => 'distance',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'nid',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 5);
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'default');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'grouping' => '',
));
$handler->override_option('row_options', array());
$handler->override_option('block_description', '');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

Comment: In the end it was an issue with the version of gmap that I had. I had to update the version to GMap Location 6.x-1.1-rc1.  

What I don't get is that they did not even seem to link to this file on the drupal web site.  It took me about 2 weeks to figure this out. 

Am I missing something about the process and how I would have known to use that version?

Comment: the main drupal search function isn't very good, but if you try searching the issue queue for each relevant module you can usually find things. On each module download page there is a link http://drupal.org/project/issues/gmap